# Returning max value in a DC.js / Crossfilter group

Tags: crossfilter, dc.js

I am wondering how to return the max value from a dc.js group.

For example:

```
  var dateDim = data.dimension(function(d) {return d.page_id;});
  var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.commodity_id;});
```

This will return a bar chart plotting page_ids on the X axis, against commodity_ids on the Y axis.

However, I would like it to return the amount of commodity_ids on that particular page on the Y axis.

Would it be accomplished with something similar to the max and min dimension functionality?

```
 var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].page_id;
 var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].page_id;
```

Apologies if the description is unclear.

Thanks

Comment: with finding max it is clear, but how to return min value on the group? Since hits.bottom does not exists...

Comment: If the question was how to obtain the minimum/maximum value of the rows within each group, I've just added [a FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#do-reductions-that-require-all-the-row-data) and [an example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/complex-reduce.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'll attempt to at least point you in the right direction.

The following lines of code will return a sum of the `commodity_id`'s grouped by `page_id`:

```
    var dateDim = data.dimension(function(d) {return d.page_id;});
    var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.commodity_id;});
```

If a page had three commodities with the following `commodity_id`'s: [ 1, 2, 5 ]
 `reduceSum` would return the value 8 for that page (1+2+5=8); it would add each subsequent `commodity_id` until it reached the end of the page.

Assuming that each entry in the dataset contains a `commodity_id` that must be counted, you can get away with just grouping and using `reduceCount` since you only care about the total number of commodities per page:

```
    var hits = dateDim.group().reduceCount();
```

This will count how many times each `page_id` appears in the database, which corresponds to the amount of `commodity_id`'s there are on that page.

If you would like to see the result of this grouping you can use:

```
    hits.all();
```

This will return an array of objects  Each object in this array contains a `key` and a `value`.  The `key` corresponds to the `page_id` and the `value` corresponds to the number of times that `page_id` occurs in the dataset.

At this point, if you'd like to get the `page_id` with the maximum value, you can use the `top()` function. (`group()` contains a `top()` function just like `dimension()`, which returns the group with the largest number of counts.)  The following is how you can access the `page_id` with the most entries in the database (which should correspond to the most amount of `commodity_id`'s) and the number of corresponding entries:

```
    var page_id_with_most_entries = hits.top(1)[0].key;
    var number_of_entries = hits.top(1)[0].value;
```

If you haven't already, check out the crossfilter.js API wiki:

https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

I also have found the annotated source code of the DC.js Nasdaq Example shown on the DC.js page helpful:

http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html

(Just remove the "docs/stock.html" from the link to get to the Nasdaq Example.)

Comment: Important to note that var hits = dateDim.group().reduceCount() has nothing to do with the commodity_id, and assumes the presence of that data in each row. If that was not true, you could do a custom reduce whose add looked like reduceAdd(p,v) {if (v.commodity_id != undefined) p.commodities++}